# Spring Integration display warning that header is ignored for population because it is is readOnly

Tags: spring-integration

I found that once I update the Spring Integration to latest v4.3.10, it shows lot of warnings that the header is ignored for population because it is is readOnly

e.g.

```
21:46:03.628 [task-scheduler-8] INFO  o.s.i.support.MessageBuilder - The header [id=2b3368ab-e04b-6082-9dbe-f6065f49739b] is ignored for population because it is is readOnly.
```

There is no such warning in earlier version of SI. What is the root cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

See here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4284.

Some headers are really read only and with that change you know which header won't be populated.

In your case the the story is about the `id` header.

You can increase logging level to `warn` for the `o.s.i.support.MessageBuilder` to avoid that noise.

Meanwhile, please, share with us the code where you build new messages and get that message in logs.

Comment: According to that JIRA issue, the intention for adding that warning is I should not use any header name which are reservered by SI. However, I couldn't find any part of my program that use "id" as header explicitly. The "id" header might be generated somewhere by SI component itself. I think it should be nice that such warning will only be shown if I wrongly chose the reserved SI header names

Comment: Yep! We decided to drop off that log altogether in the next release. We have mentioned read-only headers in the reference manual http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-construction-chapter.html#read-only-headers. So, that should be enough to protect Framework from unexpected behavior. Sorry for the noise from the first implementation